# Error: The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems

Tags: vba, macos, excel

I have the following code, written on Pro Surface 32-bit. When I try to run on Mac (64-bit) it generates an error.

> Compile error: The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems

How can I make this run?

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()

Range("a1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "11"

Dim x As Integer
x = Range("a2").Value

Dim i As Integer
For i = 6 To x: 'Replace 39 with your range'
    Range("a1").Value = i   'Replace C1 with your offset cell
    Application.Calculate
    Application.Wait Now + 1 / (24 * 60 * 60# * 1.8)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Which bit doesn't work? Can you reach a `Stop` statement introduced to the function as a first line?

Comment: when i try to run this on a mac it comes up with the 'Compile error: The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems' error?